# how to use CSerialPort in Qt?

Tags: qt, serial-port

when I add CSerialPort files(SerialPort.h, SerialPort.cpp) into my QMake project, and compile it, IDE(vc2008) throw lots of errors, How could I deal with it?

I installed vc2008, qt4.6 for windows visualstudio, and visualstudio plugin for Qt, and CSerialPort works right in normal MFC projects.

I know there is a QextSerialPort, but it is in beta condition..

Comment: Funny. I remember looking into QextSerialPost back in 2007 and it was in beta then too. I guess Trolltech has a super long testing cycle.

Comment: @jojaba: The QextSerialPort project is not affiliated in any way Nokia / Trolltech / Qt.

Comment: lots of opensource projects are in beta phase, and stable enough for industry use, I'll try to use QextSerialPort, and keep on tracking this thread.